# Convert two arrays into an array of Hash pairs

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays:

```
dates = [1,2,3]
values = [10,20,30]
```

How can I combine them like this?

```
[{date:1,value:10},{date:2,value:20}...etc]
```

Comment: Hmmm. `...etc` saves 12 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
dates.zip(values).map{|k, v| {date: k, value: v}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be:

```
dates.each_with_index.map{|d,i| {:date=>d,:value=>values[i]}}
# => [{:date=>1, :value=>10}, {:date=>2, :value=>20}, {:date=>3, :value=>30}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
dates = [1,2,3]
values = [10,20,30]

h = ([:date].product(dates)).zip([:value].product(values)).collect(&:to_h)
p h
```

**Output**

```
[{:date=>1, :value=>10}, {:date=>2, :value=>20}, {:date=>3, :value=>30}]
```

---

*PS: 
The output above though looks different, but it is same thing as you expect - a Ruby Hash.  See below for proof*

```
p [{date:1,value:10},{date:2,value:20}] # This is what you want
```

produces

```
[{:date=>1, :value=>10}, {:date=>2, :value=>20}]
```

---

Comment: I think you looked better [before you started wearing the hat](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fe/9d/95/fe9d953c8dc8edccde5ad7dec9bdf039.jpg).